# problemas con las id kivy

Tags: kivy, id, widget

tengo un problema, lo q quiero es agregar un widget (Agregar_w) al apretar un boton en la clase Get_text() y q se agregue en la clase Main() en la ruta q especifique en la funcion refresh, el problema es q no me toma la ruta, no se q es lo q escribo mal, es como q la pantalla no esta unida al screenmanager, no se q es lo q hago mal.
PD:me tira este error cuando se ejecuta refresh

self.manager.ids.menu.ids.insumo.add_widget(Agregar_w())
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'manager'

```
from pickle import OBJ
import kivy
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager, ScreenManager
import base_datos
from base_datos import *
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

bbdd = base_datos

class Vent_p(MDScreenManager):

    def Cambiar_screen(self, screen):
        self.current=screen
        self.transition.direction = 'right'

class Main(MDScreen):

    def refresh(self):
        self.manager.ids.menu.ids.insumo.add_widget(Agregar_w())

class Generar_insumo(MDScreen):
    pass
    
class Get_text(MDScreen):

    def get_insumo(self):       
        self.nom_ins=self.ids.ob1.text
        self.col=self.ids.ob2.text
        self.tam=self.ids.ob3.text
        self.cant=self.ids.ob4.text
        self.obser=self.ids.ob5.text
        bbdd.crear_insumo(self.nom_ins, self.col, self.tam, self.cant, self.obser)
        Clock.schedule_once(Main.refresh, 1)
        
class Tarjeta_ins(BoxLayout): #widget de insumo
    pass

class Agregar_w(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Agregar_w,self).__init__(**kwargs) 
        self.lista=bbdd.leer_tabla()
        for i in self.lista:
            self.add_widget(Tarjeta_ins())

class PrincipalApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette ='Blue'
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette ='Red'
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        return Builder.load_file('estructura.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    PrincipalApp().run()
```

archivo .kv

```
Vent_p:

<Vent_p>:
    name: 'screen_manager'
    Main:
        id: menu
    Generar_insumo:
    Modificar_stock:
    Configuracion:
    Get_text:

<Main>:
    name: 'menu1'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "PAKAGIN"
            anchor_title: "center"
            pos_hint:{'top':1}
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
            right_action_items: [["email", lambda x: app.callback()], ['brightness-4',lambda x: app.callback() ]]
                            
        MDBottomNavigation:
            id: bs
            selected_color_background: "#858291"
            text_color_active: "#3D73E7"

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen 1'
                text: 'Pedidos'
                icon:"notebook-multiple"
                
                ScrollView:
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    pos:self.pos
                    do_scroll_x: False
                    do_scroll_y: True
                    
                    MDGridLayout: 
                        cols: 1
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height:self.minimum_height
                        row_default_height:100
                        padding: 20
                        spacing: 10
                        #insertar widget de pedidos
             
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                
                name: 'screen 2'
                text: 'Stock'
                icon: 'package-variant'
                
                ScrollView:
                    id:sw
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    pos:self.pos
                    do_scroll_x: False
                    do_scroll_y: True
                    
                    MDGridLayout:
                        id: insumo
                        cols: 1
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height:self.minimum_height
                        row_default_height:100
                        padding: 20
                        spacing: 10
                        #insertar widget de insumos
                        Agregar_w:
                            
        
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
        MDNavigationDrawerMenu:

            MDNavigationDrawerLabel:
                text: "Menu"

            MDNavigationDrawerItem:
                icon: "package-variant-plus"
                text_right_color: "#4a4939"
                text: "Generar insumo"
                on_press: 
                    root.manager.current = 'gen_i'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    nav_drawer.set_state("close")

<Generar_insumo>:
      
    name:'gen_i'
    size: root.width,root.height
    MDScreen:
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            
            orientation:'vertical'           
            MDTopAppBar:       
                title: "GENERAR INSUMO"
                anchor_title: "center"
                pos_hint:{'top':1}      
                left_action_items: [["arrow-left-bold", lambda x: root.manager.Cambiar_screen("menu1")]]

            MDScreen:
                id: insum
                MDFloatLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    MDFloatingActionButton:
                        spacing:30
                        padding: 200
                        icon: "plus"
                        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        pos_hint:{'center_x':.8, 'center_y':.2}
                        on_press: root.manager.current = 'ms'

<Get_text>:
    name: 'ms'
    
    MDGridLayout:
        id: t1
        cols: 1
        padding: 30
        size: root.width, root.height
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size: self.size
            MDTextField:
                id: ob1
                hint_text:'Nombre del insumo'                
            MDTextField:
                id: ob2
                hint_text:'Color'
            MDTextField:
                id: ob3
                hint_text:'Tamaño'
            MDTextField:
                id: ob4
                hint_text:'Cantidad'
            MDTextField:
                id: ob5
                hint_text:'Comentarios'
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y:.6
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Guardar"
                md_bg_color: "blue"
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
                on_press: 
                    root.get_insumo()
                    root.manager.current= 'menu1'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
<Tarjeta_ins>:
    MDCard:
        id: ti
        elevation: 3
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 2
            
<Agregar_w>:
    id: agr_w
    size: root.width,root.height
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la estructura que estás usando para referirte a los Ids, como aquí:

```
self.manager.ids.menu.ids.insumo.add_widget(Agregar_w())
```

La forma correcta es siempre utilizar

```
self.root.ids.NOMBRE_DEL_WIDGET
```

Ejemplo:

```
self.root.ids.menu.ids.insumo.add_widget(Agregar_w())
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa porque confunde la id del objeto con el atributo. Para eso tienes primero que acceder a su id y desde ahí a su atributo. Pero claro no es tan directo, cada contenedor raíz guarda todas sus id de sus objetos declaradas en un diccionario.
Tendrás 1º que ponerle id a los contenedores raíz alos que quieras acceder y ya desde aquí podrás acceder a sus keywork de sus objetos a través de la función ids.

Por ejemplo al final del 1º contenedor que lanzas, dibuja dibujas el 2º contenedor raíz o al que quieras acceder desde una llamada a este, esto se pone al final del 1º con su indentación correspondiente. Supongamos que el 2º contenedor es el que tiene el objeto al que llamamos, entonces le ponemos una id y lo dibujamos:

Generar_insumo:
id: Generar  (esta línea iría debajo con su indentación)

(por ejemplo la id: Generar) eso en el contenedor raíz que vaya a llamar al otro contenedor raíz, se coloca al final del mismo. Ya después, en el botón que realizas la acción de llamada al otro objeto del otro contenedor, tienes que realizar la llamada a su id y después a su atributo:

Generar_insumo.ids['id del objeto llamado'].atributo